# back button arrow not functioning in toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

The back button arrow in the Toolbar is not working for some reason, tried some stuff but no success. The activity is on "AppTheme" and I also have "parentActivityName", but it's still not working.

this is the ImageDeatilActvity class,

```
public class ImageDeatilActvity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener {

    private boolean mIsFullScreen;

    private androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_deatil_actvity);

        mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
        if (mToolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(username);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            final Drawable upArrow = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material);
            upArrow.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
        }

        mIsFullScreen = true;

        String path = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
        PhotoView photoView = (PhotoView) findViewById(R.id.photo_view);
        photoView.setOnPhotoTapListener((view, x, y) -> updateView());

        Glide.with(this).load(path).into(photoView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
        if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
            mIsFullScreen = false;
        }

        updateView();
    }

    public void updateView() {
        mIsFullScreen = !mIsFullScreen;

        if (mIsFullScreen) {
            hideSystemUI();
        } else {
            showSystemUI();
        }
    }

    private void hideSystemUI() {
        mToolbar.animate().translationY(-mToolbar.getHeight()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2)).start();
    }

    private void showSystemUI() {
        mToolbar.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2)).start();
    }

    public int getStatusBarHeight() {
        int result = 0;
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    /*
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
    }
     */
}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".utils.ImageDeatilActvity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#33000000"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"/>



    <com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
        android:id="@+id/photo_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I also added parentActivityName for this activity but nothing happens, Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to override `onOptionsItemSelected()` method, and finish the activity when the id equals to the home button id `android.R.id.home`

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            this.finish();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Now you are using a custom ActionBar, so set the app/activity theme to `NoActionBar` in the styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">

</resources>
```

Make sure you apply it to the App manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="....">

    <application
        ...
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: Hey sorry that i didn't include the whole activity, but that method already exist but still not working :( the back button does work but not the arrow on the toolbar

Comment: @kjmb is the onOptionsItemSelected method called ?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yes it is, i have added the whole activity class please take a look.

Comment: it works now, added:
 mToolbar.bringToFront();  Thank you guys for thinking with me